# Aardvark I2C API with VB causing exception

Tags: vb.net, api, exception

I have a Aardvard I2C/SPI Dongle (http://www.totalphase.com/products/aardvark-i2cspi/) that works great with their supplied GUI. I wanted to integrate the tool into my own test GUI. I am using MS Visual Studio Express 2013. They provide an API package for VB.NET (http://www.totalphase.com/downloads/) which is contained in an aardvark_net.dll. When I run their Example, I get the following error during runtime:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe
Additional information: The type initializer for 'TotalPhase.AardvarkApi' threw an exception.
```

It breaks when the code tries to call their AardvarkApi.aa_find_devices() routine.

I also created my own project, added thr aardvark_net.dll to the project references, and the following code:

```
Imports TotalPhase
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MsgBox("Detecting Aardvark adapters...")
        Dim num As Long
        Dim devices(15) As UShort

        ' Find all the attached devices
        Try
        num = AardvarkApi.aa_find_devices(16, devices)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Same thing, the program throws and exceptions at the AardvarkApi.aa_find_devices() and the exception message is:

```
The type initializer for 'TotalPhase.AardvarkApi' threw an exception.
```

I tried going to Exception Settings and unchecking the Thrown bixes, but no change.

I am savvy enough to get something created in VB (I am not apt at what is connectedon the other end of the Aardvark Dongle!), but I could use some help with this.

Thank you,
~Brett

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! I was using the API from the website, but I have the device drivers from the disk. Up dated the device drivers and it went away. (Curiously though, the example solution still throws exceptions, but my project does not... using the same DLLs)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while trying to connect through C# GUI. The console application was working fine. I changed the CPU setting to "Any CPU" and it works fine. By default it was set to x86. 
My code:

```
namespace _test_project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int port = 0;
        int handle;        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int numElem = 20;
            ushort[] ports = new ushort [20];
            uint[] uniqueIds = new uint[20];
            int i=0;


            int count = AardvarkApi.aa_find_devices_ext(numElem, ports, numElem, uniqueIds);

            i = 20;                    

            handle = AardvarkApi.aa_open(port);

            if (handle <= 0)
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = " Aardvark Not connected";
                //Console.WriteLine("Unable to open Aardvark device on port {0}", port);

                toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Error: " + Convert.ToString(AardvarkApi.aa_status_string(handle));
                //Console.WriteLine("error: {0}", AardvarkApi.aa_status_string(handle));
                //return;
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Aardvark connected";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which of their Windows API packages you download. It must match the CPU selection you build with. I initially had this problem building an "Any CPU", with "Prefer 32-bit" C# application in VS2017, but it turned out I had downloaded the 64-bit API. That package did work when I removed the "Prefer 32-bit", or when I built as x64.

Since the application is 32-bit for compatibility with another DLL, I couldn't use a 64-bit build. But the 32-bit build worked once I downloaded the 32-bit DLL.